# Ember.js: Too weird - property skipped when name is changed

Tags: properties, ember.js, observers

I have two computed properties, both of which are functioning normally.  But when I change the name of the property (and nothing else) ember no longer triggers them.

I am not changing the properties they observe so it does not make sense that changing the name of the property would make any difference.  Likewise, when I create more computed properties that watch the same property, those are never hit.  WTF??

**Screen cast**: http://screencast.com/t/YXQDMprzSFW - see it work (and not)

**Properties of this model:** focusing on `selectedQuantity` and `selectedCost`

```
App.Item = Ember.Object.extend({

    // item descriptive properties
    identity: 'model: Item',
    id: '',                                             // numeric id matching node id
    slug: '',                                           // identifier suitable for css classes
    title: '',
    subtitle: '',
    description: '',
    image: '',
    category: '', 
    isActive: false,

    // item data collections
    options: [],
    properties: [],

    // flag to indicate a change in option selections

    // percent of VEC portfolio
    percentVec: function(){
        var p = this.get('values').findBy('type', 'percentVec');
        if(typeof p != 'undefined') { p = parseInt(p.quantity, 10); }
        else { p = ''; }
        return p;
    }.property('values.@each'),

    // current quantity
    selectedQuantity: function(){
        var opt = this.get('options').findBy('isSelected', true); 
        var q = (typeof opt != 'undefined') ? opt.get('quantity') : 0; 
        return parseInt(q, 10);
    }.property('options.@each.isSelected'),

    // current cost
    selectedCost: function(){
        var j = this.get('options').reduce(function(prevCost, currentOption, index, array){ 
            if(currentOption.get('isSelected')) return currentOption.get('cost');
            else return prevCost;
        }, 0);
        return j;
    }.property('options.@each.isSelected'), 

    // localized base cost
    vtCost: function(){
        var c = this.get('values').findBy('type', 'costVt');
        if(typeof c != 'undefined') { c = parseInt(c.cost, 10); } 
        else { c = ''; }
        return c;
    }.property('values.@each')

})
.reopen({

    hasProperty: function( prop ){
        var properties = this.get('properties');
        return (typeof properties[prop] != 'undefined') ? true : false;
    }

});
```

This doesn't feel like a coding problem - feels more like a caching problem or something, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: are you calling at some point those properties ? not consumed properties are never calculated. take a look at this page http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html go to this title "UNCONSUMED COMPUTED PROPERTIES DO NOT TRIGGER OBSERVERS". And you can also get some nice ideas on how to write nice code for properties in that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal.

Those are computed properties. You are most likely rendering both computed properties like this `{{selectedCost}}` & `{{selectedQuantity}}` in your handlebars template.

Renaming one of those only in your controller causes ember not computing, since they aren't needed.

You could always use `.observers(..)` if you want to respond on a changed value.

**Edit**
Also note,

Declaring your object like this:

```
App.Item = Ember.Object.extend({

    // item descriptive properties
    identity: 'model: Item',
    ...
}
```

Means that your `identity` field is shared between all `App.Item`s.
Make sure to use the `set` function. Eg: `this.set('identity','model: Item')`

Comment: Thanks. I thought I could make that change & test it before rolling the change out to my handlebars templates, ect.  Have to remember not to do that.. : )